# Recombining two photons coming from independent sources

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, optics, photons, wavefunction

My question is about the image below.

Photon $A$ comes from the left and goes through a beam splitter, photon $B$ comes from the right and also passes through a beam splitter. The upper and lower paths of photon $A$ and $B$ are recombined at beam splitters.

Detectors $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ are behind the lower beam splitter, $D_{3}$ and $D_{4}$ are behind the upper beam splitter. Moreover, on its upper path photon $A$ passes through phase plate $\phi_{1}$, on its lower path through phase plate $\phi_{2}$, $B$ passes through plase plates $\phi_{3}$ and $\phi_{4}$.

My question is what are the odds of detecting both photons at the upper detectors, or both at the lower detectors? My naive intuition is that because half of the probability wave on each side goes up, and half goes down, we will never find both photons at $D_{1}$/$D_{2}$ or both at $D_{3}$/$D_{4}$, but maybe this is too naive...

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

With some more thought, I actually think that also in this set-up two photons can be detected either at D1/D2 or at D3/D4. So my follow-up question would be: what are the odds of combinations of detector hits (e.g. odds of clicks at D1 and D3) as a function of the phase plates? Or do these phase plates not affect the odds?

[image]

Comment: Hi Solomon, Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Hi Solomon, Thank you for your reply!

My reasoning is as follows.
1) A single photon has no well-defined phase, so the phase plates should be irrelevant.
2) This situation can essentially be described by a tensor product between the wavefunction of both photons. If we  take HOM interference into account,  we end up with 1/8 : two hits at D1, 1/8: 2 at D2, 1/8: 2 hits at D3, 1/8: 2 hits at D4, 1/8: D1/D3, 1/8: D1/D4, 1/8: D2/D3, 1/8: D2/D4.
The phase plates are irrelevant.

Comment: To expand on the tensor product idea:

tensor product between the wavefunction of both photons, if we denote 0 as upper path and 1 as lower path, we simply have PSI = 1/sqrt(2) * (|0> + |1>) for each photon, so the tensor product is 1/2*(|0>|0> + |0>|1> + |1>|0> + |1>|1>).
If we take the complex conjugate of this wavefunction, we obtain HOM interference in the case of |0>|0> and |1>|1>, and no interference in the cases of |0>|1> and |1>|0>.

Comment: Anyway, curious to know if this is (somewhat) accurate, or if my approach is too simplistic.

Comment: I was unaware of the HOM Effect. Like I said in my original comment, I am no expert. I will delete that comment now. Your question is beyond my competence.